# Accessing static methods from instance in Typescript

Tags: javascript, static, typescript

Why can't I do this? Is it due to technical limitations of Javascript/Typescript, or is this a design decision by the developers of Typescript? This same code would work fine in Java or C#.

```
class Test {
  static str: string = "test";
  public static getTest(): string {
    return this.str;
  }
}

//works as expected
console.log(Test.getTest());
//won't compile
var test: Test = new Test();
console.log(test.getTest());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but I'd still like to know why.

Less magic. Static properties exist on the `Class` not instances. Its clear exactly what is getting called from the code instead of magic binding to class or member function at runtime.

> Is it due to technical limitations of Javascript/Typescript, or is this a design decision by the developers of Typescript

Not a technical limitation. A design decision. More to align with ES6 than anything else : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static But over there its a decision made for less magic

Comment: Updated my question to have a clearer question: Is it due to technical limitations of Javascript/Typescript, or is this a design decision by the developers of Typescript? It sounds like you're telling me its the latter to make things clearer to a developer.

Answer (score 6):

As @basarat says, it's just a design decision, not a technical limitation.

Actually, even though it's not possible to access `test.getTest()` just like you would in Java or C#, there are ways to access it:

Both [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) (replacement to the now deprecated [`Object.prototype.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)) or [`Object.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) should work:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(test).constructor.getTest();

test.constructor.getTest();
```

Actually:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(test).constructor === test.constructor; // true
```

Here you can see the compiled source in action:

```js
class Test {
  static getTest() {
    return this.str;
  }
}

Test.str = 'test';

const test = new Test();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(test).constructor.getTest());
console.log(test.constructor.getTest());

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(test).constructor === test.constructor);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(test) === Test.prototype);
```

Note static properties exist in classes but not in instances.

Therefore, if you want to go from `test` to its prototype, you should call `Object.getPrototypeOf(test)`, not `test.prototype`, which is a completely different thing.

The `.prototype` property only exists in functions and, when instantiating a new object using `new` and a call to that constructor function (`new Test()`), will become the newly created object's prototype (the deprecated `.__proto__`).

In your example:

```
test.prototype;                     // undefined
Test;                               // class Test { static getTest() { ... } }
Test.protoype;                      // { constructor: class Test { ... } }
Test.protoype.constructor;          // class Test { static getTest() { ... } }
Test.protoype.constructor === Test; // true
test.constructor;                   // class Test { static getTest() { ... } }
test.constructor === Test;          // true

Object.getPrototypeOf(test) === Test.prototype; // true
```