# I have a question for Typescript static function

Tags: typescript

Here is my code.

```js
class BaseClass {
   // some static method
   static someMethod() {
   }
}
```

```js
class ChildClass extends BaseClass{

}
```

```js
class AnotherClass {
   protected variable: BaseClass; // It works while the type is any

   protected someFunction() {
      return this.variable.someMethod(); // Editor shows that there's no someMethod in BaseClass
   }
}
```

The problem is , I want the protected variable in AnotherClass store the class function , not the class instance.

is It possible ?

Thanks.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing static methods from instance in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864167/accessing-static-methods-from-instance-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `variable` property is an instance of the `BaseClass`, not the class itself.

The type of `variable` needs to be the type of `BaseClass`, i.e. `typeof BaseClass`:

```
class AnotherClass {
  protected variable: typeof BaseClass;

  public constructor(v: typeof BaseClass) {
    this.variable = v;
  }

  protected someFunction() {
    return this.variable.someMethod();
  }
}


const a: AnotherClass = new AnotherClass(BaseClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by tsc not by editor.

Point out some problems in your code.

```
class AnotherClass {
    protected variable: BaseClass; // This is mean variable is instance of BaseClass
    protected someFunction() {
        return this.variable.someMethod(); // So you cannot access a static method of an instance
    }
}
```

If you want to access the static method of a class. You should call from the class object, not the instance of class. So you should modify the type of variable member from `BaseClass` to `typeof BaseClass`
The following is a simple sample. To simply the concept, I modify the encapsulation of members.

```
class BaseClass {
  static someMethod(): void {}
}

class DeriveClass extends BaseClass {
}

class AnotherClass {
    public variable: typeof BaseClass = BaseClass;
    public someFunction() {
        return this.variable.someMethod();
    }
}

let instance = new AnotherClass();
instance.variable = DeriveClass; // This is accepted, because DeriveClass extended from BaseClass
instance.someFunction();
```